# SQL top and then where

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I am running MSSQLServer2008. 
Is it possible (in one step) to select the first n table entries and then perform a where query only on those n entries? 
To (hopefully) clarify: I do not want to select the n entries, where the criterion was met; but only those entries where the criterion was met in the first n rows. 
Best, 
Christian

Comment: can you please explain your question in brief or in pictorial view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT TOP 100 * FROM TableName)M
WHERE-- Your Condition Here
```

Comment: Of course the inner select should have an ORDER BY clause for TOP to work in predictable way

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you also for the fast response! May I ask, what does the M stand for, or where could I get more information about this kind of nested queries?

Comment: This is Just temp Name given to Inner Query result

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you.